# Compute Galois group of these extensions.

Tags: galois-theory

I think that I have a problem in the redaction. I have to compute

> **1)** $G=\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 2)/\mathbb Q)$

I know that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 2)$ is the splitting field of $X^4-10X^2+1$, and that the roots of $X^4-10X+1$ are given by $$\{\sqrt 3+\sqrt 2; \sqrt 3-\sqrt 2;\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3;-\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3\}$$

Then I would define 
$$\sigma _1: \sqrt 3+\sqrt 2\mapsto \sqrt 3-\sqrt 2$$
$$\sigma _2: \sqrt 3+\sqrt 2\mapsto \sqrt 2-\sqrt 3$$
$$\sigma _3: \sqrt 3+\sqrt 2\mapsto -\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3$$
$$\sigma _4: \sqrt 3-\sqrt 2\mapsto \sqrt 2-\sqrt 3$$
$$\sigma _5: \sqrt 3-\sqrt 2\mapsto -\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3$$
$$\sigma _6: \sqrt 2-\sqrt 3\mapsto -\sqrt 2-\sqrt3$$

I remark that $\sigma_3=\sigma_4$, $\sigma _1=\sigma _6$ and $\sigma _2=\sigma _6$ therefore I can eliminate $\sigma _4,\sigma _5$ and $\sigma _6$. Therefore $G=\{1,\sigma _1,\sigma _2,\sigma _3\}\cong\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ because all element are of order $2$. Is my resolution correct ?

> **2)** $G=\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]2)/\mathbb Q)$

I know that $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]2)$ is the splitting field of $X^4-2$ and that the root of $X^2-2$ are the elements of $\{\sqrt[4]2,-\sqrt[4]2,i\sqrt[4]2,-i\sqrt[4]2\}$. But now, I don't know how to continue... I know that the answer is $D_8$, but I have problem to represent it.

> **3)** $G=\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4] 5)/\mathbb Q)$

I know that $X^4-5$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]5$ and that only the solution $\pm\sqrt[4]5$ are in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]5)$. But the problem is that I only find $id$ and the automorphism $\sigma :\sqrt[4]5\mapsto -\sqrt[4]5$ but we should have $4$ automorphism, not 2 because $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]5):\mathbb Q]=4$ therefore I would need some help.

Thanks,

Comment: Some hints: in 1: you don't need the polynomial; instead you can just ask what the possible images of the generators $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ are. In 3, it's _not_ always true that the size of the Galois group is equal to the degree: that's a theorem for Galois extensions, but this extension isn't Galois, because $X^4-5$ doesn't split in that extension. (A similar more extreme example is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbf Q.$)

Comment: So is 3) correct ?

Comment: Yes! By the way, it's not clear to me what your question is in 1): what do you want to know?

Comment: Is my resolution correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think it is essentially correct. But the way you have listed the elements $\sigma_i$ is confusing. First of all, you get repetitions, as you noted, but that's not so bad. More seriously, how do you know that your definitions specify the automorphisms $\sigma_i$ completely?

Comment: I don't understand your last question (sorry, i'm not english). And for the the second resolution ? How can I do ?

Comment: For example: look at your formula for $\sigma_1$. It tells me where **one** element of the field is sent to. Why does this formula actually specify where **every** element of the field is sent to?